# Pass multiple params via Firebase Dynamic links Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, firebase-invites

I've used Firebase Dynamics link and it can open my app, go to play store or go to an URL. But when I pass some parameters through link, I can only get first parameter.
Here's my dynamic links:

```
https://xx.app.goo.gl/?link=http://xx.com/?usn=abc&pass=def&apn=com.xx&afl=http://google.com
```

And I used this code to get the link:

```
// Build GoogleApiClient with AppInvite API for receiving deep links
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .addApi(AppInvite.API)
                .build();

        // Check if this app was launched from a deep link. Setting autoLaunchDeepLink to true
        // would automatically launch the deep link if one is found.
        boolean autoLaunchDeepLink = false;
        AppInvite.AppInviteApi.getInvitation(mGoogleApiClient, this, autoLaunchDeepLink)
                .setResultCallback(
                        result -> {
                            if (result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                // Extract deep link from Intent
                                Intent intent = result.getInvitationIntent();
                                String deepLink = AppInviteReferral.getDeepLink(intent);
                                Logger.e(deepLink);
                            }
                        }
                );
```

And the log print: http://xx.com/?usn=abc (the pass=def was lost)
Anyone resolve this issue?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to [URL encode](http://www.w3schools.com/Tags/ref_urlencode.asp) the value of the `link` parameter, otherwise the system can't tell what is a parameter of the Dynamic Link and what is a sub-paramater of the `link` parameter of the Dynamic Link.

This means the final URL should look like `https://xx.app.goo.gl/?link=http%3A%2F%2Fxx.com%2F%3Fusn%3Dabc%26pass%3Ddef&apn=com.xx&afl=http://google.com`

**Important note:** if you are (as I suspect) attempting to pass usernames and passwords through as plaintext link parameters, this is an *incredibly bad idea.* Seriously, ***do not do this***. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39672655/5394680) for the proper approach to a requirement like this.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it. The usn/pass is just for testing purpose :D

Comment: please help with this similar question too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42119692/6144372

Answer (score -1):

Simply as you pass in url:

https://*link.example.com*?**param="value1"**&**param2="value2"** ...